# Could we use cucumber to execute java step definitions - not cucumber -jvm

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

Is there any way to call cucumber to exe some feature files that is written in java? (not as Junit)

Normally for ruby you can say cucumber features/somefeature.feature and it will exe step definitions in somefeature.rb

And for cpp you can do similar to call cucumber to to exe step definitions in cpp through wire protocol.

What my question is, is there any similar implementation in java, that you can call cucumber to exe step definitions in java.

I understand you can run cucumber - jvm as part of Junit test through mvn or gradle.

But I do not want to run this BDD test as part of the building process. I want to call cucumber at the last step in the CI, and it will exe any step definitions in Ruby, Cpp, Java

Comment: I don't understand "I do not want to run this BDD test as part of the building process. I want to call cucumber at the last step in the CI". What's the difference?

Comment: In the current building process, we call mvn install, which will also exe the bdd test as part of maven build. want to separate those. Since our implementation is running this bdd test as Junit test. What we want to achieve eventually is to have everything build. Then calling cucumber and then it will pick one line on feature file and then it will exe the corresponding step definitions in any of CPP, JAVA, RUBY code. For now, we could only do CPP and ruby because cucumber-jvm is running as part of Junit test. It does not support wire protocol like CPP.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber-JVM can be executed from a JUnit runner. It can also be executed from a command line without using a JUnit runner. It sounds to that the last option is what you want.

Explore the [CLI Runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner) and you might find something that fulfills your requirements.

Comment: I would attempt to redefine the problem. I.e. One build step for cucumber-jvm, one build step for cucumber-cpp, and another for cucumber-ruby. I would have the three run concurrently.  CLI Runner is a pain to setup and you would need different dependencies for each cucumber variant. Thomas, you could do it.  Lesser mortals, not so much. :-)